# Strange visual studio compiler error, :N0.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I am working on a project using visual studio 2013 as an IDE, with a solution file that was generated from cmake. I have encountered this strange error that does not allow me to build my code with the release configuration, even though the code worked fine in the debug configuration. The error is the following:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file ':N0.obj'
```

Not sure why this occurs as I have never seen nor created a N0.obj file.
The Out put window gives me this:

```
3>  Generating Code...
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ':NO.obj'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would look at your sources listed in your project file.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... Look at sources in project, look though all files use C+F "NO.obj" or "N0.obj". Find and fix problem. If that does not work just skip cmake and because you are using visual studio new->project from existing code... follow prompts.